# Setting up an A* search

Tags: java, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I am writing a small section of a program in which i have to write up a pathfinding algorithm. The function takes in what will be known as 'routes' that each define a start and end point in 2D space. The algorithm is required to find the shortest and most efficient (to a degree) path (from the origin) to take through these routes, minimising the total distance traveled overall.

I did a bit of research and started down a path that i thought might work. So far i have converted the routes into a directed graph which is all linked up as if it were an idealised road map. I then attempted to perform an A* search on this graph. The heuristic i used calculates the total distance of the 'routes' left to travel and the distance from start (G) value i used was just the cumulative distance traveled to get to the current point. This works for some input but others return no path at all and i cant seem to figure out why.

Is is possible that my heuristic is wrong and this is causing a miscalculation somewhere or is it more likely that the A* procedure itself is wrong? or am i just on completely the wrong track here?

I'll put the getPath function below (written in Java) just in case that helps.

Thanks in advance.

```
public ArrayList<Vector2> getPath()
{
    PriorityQueue<SearchNode> openList = new PriorityQueue<SearchNode>(10, new SearchNodeComparator());
    ArrayList<SearchNode> closedList = new ArrayList<SearchNode>();

    map.startJobs();
    searchDepth = 0;

    SearchNode start = searchableGraph.getNode(new Vector2(0, 0));
    int goalsLeft = map.getJobCount();

    start.setDistanceTraveled(0);

    openList.add(start);

    while (openList.size() > 0)
    {
        SearchNode current = openList.peek();
        searchDepth++;

        if (map.isJobEndPoint(current.getValue()))
        {
            map.completeJob(current.getValue());
            goalsLeft--;

        }

        if (reachedGoalState(current, searchableGraph.getNodes().size()))
        {
            return getFinalPath(current);
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<SearchNode> neighbours = getNeighbours(current);

            for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++)
            {
                SearchNode node = neighbours.get(i);        
                System.out.print("Inspecting node" + node.getValue().toString());

                float distanceTraveled = current.getDistanceTraveled() + getDistance(current.getValue(), node.getValue());

                float heuristic = heuristic(node);

                if (!openList.contains(node) && !closedList.contains(node))
                {

                    node.setDistanceTraveled(distanceTraveled);

                    node.setDistanceToGoal(distanceTraveled + heuristic);

                    node.setParent(current);

                    openList.add(node);
                }
                else if(openList.contains(node))
                {
                    if (node.getDistanceTraveled() <= distanceTraveled)
                    {

                        node.setDistanceToGoal(distanceTraveled + heuristic);


                        node.setParent(current);
                    }

                }
            }

            openList.remove(current);
            closedList.add(current);
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<Vector2>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The heuristic i used calculates the total distance of the 'routes' left to travel

The heuristic used by A* must be [admissible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic); that is, it must **never *over*​estimate the distance to the end**.

If I understand your description correctly, your heuristic is not admissible, so is not guaranteed to work.